# Cant access to local host with WeatherForecast webapp

Tags: .net, localhost, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a new .NET web app project in my visual studio code, by default is the WeatherForecast web app.
After writing dotnet run i get this as output

[firts output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZlMS.png)

So I tried to go on the first localhost link, but didn't work...
Even the second link don't work.
I get this error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAzUp.png)

Could you help me?

Comment: do not add images in ques. and also if you hide the url how will you expect us to provide the ans. but still based on whatever you have given try adding controller name just giving base path will not take you anywhere.

Comment: try accessing https://localhost:7261/weatherforecast and see if you are able to access or not.